# R: Plot legend formatting

Tags: r, plot, legend

I'm running this code on Mac (OS X Yosemite 10.10.2)

```
par(bg = "transparent")
with(FilteredDates, plot(DateTime, Sub_metering_1, xlab=NA, ylab="Energy Sub metering",lty=1, lwd=1, pch=".", type="n"))
with(FilteredDates, lines(DateTime, Sub_metering_1,lty=1, lwd=1, pch="."))
with(FilteredDates, lines(DateTime, Sub_metering_2,lty=1, lwd=1, pch=".", col="red"))
with(FilteredDates, lines(DateTime, Sub_metering_3,lty=1, lwd=1, pch=".", col="blue"))
legend("topright", legend=c("Sub_metering_1","Sub_metering_2","Sub_metering_3"),cex=0.7, lty=1, col=c("black","red","blue"))
dev.copy(png, file="plot3.png", width=480,height=480, type="quartz")
dev.off()
```

As a result, I need a square *png* file 480x480.
The default graphic type is "quartz".

But my legend doesn't fit the box:
[image: my plot]

What did I make wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You could try manually setting the `text.width` argument of `legend`. However, it should automatically default to the appropriate length, i.e. the length of the longest string in the `legend` argument. I suspect this is a consequence of using `dev.copy` and therein specifying width and height explicitly.

Try directly plotting to the PNG device by using the following commands:

```
png("plot3b.png", width=480, height=480, type="quartz")
par(bg = "transparent")

plot(DateTime, Sub_metering_1, xlab=NA, ylab="Energy Sub metering",lty=1, lwd=1, pch=".", type="n")
lines(DateTime, Sub_metering_1, lty=1, lwd=1, pch=".")
lines(DateTime, Sub_metering_2, lty=1, lwd=1, pch=".", col="red")
lines(DateTime, Sub_metering_3, lty=1, lwd=1, pch=".", col="blue")
legend("topright", legend=c("Sub_metering_1","Sub_metering_2","Sub_metering_3"), cex=0.7, lty=1, col=c("black","red","blue"))

dev.off()
```